# Unity3D обращение к одинаковым переменным int в разных скриптах, при условии что у каждого gameObject есть только 1 скрипт

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть пуля (часть её кода ниже) она хочет уменьшить показатель HP у скрипта того игрового объекта к которому прикоснётся, у этого объекта может быть или Solder или Tank или Helicopter. Я бы хотел не проверять есть ли там такой скрипт а обращаться к любому скрипту т.к. там точно есть HP в каждом.

```
    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<Solder> ().HP -= damage;
        Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

Есть ли возможность упростить обращение к единственному скрипту в объекте при условии что там точно в каждом будет переменная HP

Comment: Судя по описанию, лучше как минимум использовать наследование. И нет, пускай даже на объект всегда 1 компонент - так "быстро" искать его нельзя - так уж устроены внутренности Unity. Единственный выход, который пока что пришел в голову - сохранить все ссылки на эти компоненты в каком-нибудь словаре по ключу в виде какого-нибудь id. Быстрее ли это, чем искать компоненты через `GetComponent` - зависит от кол-ва таких объектов.

Comment: Еще можно решить задачу через интерфейсы. Тут уж кому что больше нравится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сказал что путь изначально выбран слегка неправильный.

1. Использование `.GetComponent<IBaseUnit>()` в таком месте -- это плохой тон. Во время рантайма так делать нежелательно -- снижает производительность. Такое нужно делать исключительно на `Start()` или `Awake()`. Поэтому это нужно как-то обойти. А что если это автоматная очередь? То что тогда? Искать компонент на обьекте с каждой пулей?
2. ты не уничтожаешь пулю. она у тебя вечная :) Тоже не есть хорошо... особенно для всяких пулеметов. Хотя... может быть ты задаешь время существования в логике пули.... но, подозреваю, что навряд ли. **(кстате, это тоже желательно сделать!)**
3. Если отвечать на изначально неправильный подход и на заданный вопрос -- то наследование, как сказал **Riot**, или как пример написал **Александрр Даниловский**.

Я тут быстренько накатал тебе решение:

```
 using UnityEngine; 
 using System.Collections;
 
 public class EnemyHealthBase : MonoBehaviour { 
 protected _isLive = true;
 public int MaxHealth = 100; 
 private int _currHealth;
 
 //initialization 
 void Start () 
 { 
      _currHealth = MaxHealth;// обьект всегда появляется с максимальным здоровьем
 } 
 
 // Update 
 void Update () { 
     // враг умирает только раз
     if (_isLive && _currHealth < 1){ 
        Death();
     }
 } 
 
 private Death()
 {
    _isLive = false;
    
    // логика смерти. Например, проиграть анимацию смерти 
    // Если должен оставатся труп то дестроить обьект не нужно. 
    // Но скрипт это уже учитывает
 }
 
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) { 
     if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")//работает значительно быстрее чем .GetComponent<>()
     { 
        _currHealth -= 20;
        Destroy(col.other);// уничтожаем пулю
     } 
 }
```

Только добавь тэг "bullet" на обьект пули. Если ты имеешь несколько типов пуль -- то можешь подписать их как "bullet20"(урон 20) или "bullet50"(урон 50) и учитывать это через Switch/Case все в этом же скрипте.

Как видишь:

1. ты получаешь 1 единый скрипт который ты можешь вешать на любого врага
2. ты не используешь поиск обьектов или компонентов в обьектах в рантайме
3. при этом не нужно плодить скрипты. А если же скрипт c жизнями должен иметь какую-то свою собственную логику -- тогда ты это решаешь через наследование от даного класса но не наследуешся уже от MonoBehavior как тебе предлагает юнити изначально.

я не уверен есть ли отличия в использовании Collision для 2д обьектов, если есть -- это нужно учитывать в верхнем скрипте т.к. писал я ориентируясь на 3д. Но на 2д подход тот же должен быть.

Comment: Ну такое, я бы не сказал, что сравнение тэгов будет сильно быстрее, чем поиск единственное кастомного компонента через `GetComponent<>()`. Да и поиск компонента - не такая уж и долгая операция, как любят писать в документации, она медленная, но от десятка таких операций за кадр никто не умрет :)

Comment: Действительно. Мне очень нравится вариант с распознаванием тегов. Правда придётся задавать для разных пуль разные теги и этот способ выглядит не очень красивым. Зато понятный для новичка. Интерфейсы попробовал не догнал...
Спасибо, использую это! 
@Александр Даниловский спасибо, но я пока не смог интерфейсами. 
Riot Спасибо!

Comment: @RiotBr3aker ну я согласен что в документации по поводу этого несколько преувеличивают. Но, все же, теги будут быстрее. В таких мелочах нужно все равно привыкать к более быстрому подходу. Тем более, что это не так уж и усложнит жизнь. Потом нужно будет меньше ломать голову с оптимизациями кода что бы он работал быстрее. А этот момент наступает на каждом релизе)

Comment: @Andrew говоря конкретно про этот случай - не уверен, один тэг конечно быстрее, но вот вариант switch/case уже вызывается сомнения для 20+ тэгов. А вообще тут надо смотреть на всю игру, сказать максимально оптимальный выход на таком низком уровне нереально :)

Answer (score 0):

Первые два способа решения Вашей проблемы, которые приходят на ум, - это **наследование** (как писал выше  @RiotBr3aker) и **интерфейсы**.

**1. Через общий класс-родитель**
У классов Solder, Tank и Helicopter должен быть общий класс-родитель:

```
public class BaseUnit: MonoBehaviour
{
    public int HP;
}
```

И тогда код обработки коллизии у пули будет иметь примерно следующий вид:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    other.gameObject.GetComponent<BaseUnit>().HP -= damage;
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

**2. Через использование интерфейса**
Создадим интерфейс со свойством HP для реализации урона

```
public interface IBaseUnit
{
    int HP { get; set; }
}
```

Применяем интерфейс (на примере класса солдата)

```
public class Solder: MonoBehaviour, IBaseUnit
{
    public int HP { get; set; }

    //остальной код класса...
}
```

И тогда код обработки коллизии у пули будет иметь примерно следующий вид:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    other.gameObject.GetComponent<IBaseUnit>().HP -= damage;
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

Comment: using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public interface IBaseUnit {
 int HP { get; set;}
}
public class Tank : MonoBehaviour, IBaseUnit {
 public int HP {get; set;}

Я добавил interface к Tank видимо я полностью ошибаюсь), но как мне в редакторе задать переменную HP=10 например как я делал в public... и я не понимаю что нужно написать в  { get; set;}